# PostgreSQL, distinct, order by and parentheses

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct

I have the following request:

```
select distinct m1.firstname, m1.surname 
  from cd.members as m1 
  join cd.members as m2 on m2.recommendedby = m1.memid 
  order by m1.surname, m1.firstname;
```

and it works fine. But this one:

```
select distinct m1.firstname, m1.surname 
  from cd.members as m1 
  join cd.members as m2 on m2.recommendedby = m1.memid 
  order by (m1.surname, m1.firstname);
```

gives me the error:

```
ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

I can't understand when I have to use parentheses and when not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres has the concept of *tuples* or [*composite types*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/rowtypes.html).  These are scalar values that appear together -- much like a record or struct in many programming languages.

You can use tuples for expressions, such as:

```
where (m1.surname, m1.firstname) in ( ('a', 'b'), ('x', 'y') )
```

The problem with your `order by` expression is that the tuple is not in the `select`.  You *could* solve this by using parentheses there too:

```
select distinct (m1.firstname, m1.surname)
from cd.members m1 join
     cd.members m2
     on m2.recommendedby = m1.memid 
order by (m1.surname, m1.firstname);
```

But I would stick with the parentheses-less version, which is standard SQL and works in all databases.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot for the answer